# JVM exited while loading the application for Java Service Wrapper

Tags: java, service, jvm

I am using Java service Wrapper Version 3.1.2 and java 1.8 OS: Windows.
I cannot install service in 32 bit which shows the following error

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2021/10/30 13:12:45 | Launching a JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2021/10/30 13:12:45 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2021/10/30 13:12:49 | Launching a JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2021/10/30 13:12:49 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2021/10/30 13:12:53 | Launching a JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2021/10/30 13:12:53 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2021/10/30 13:12:58 | Launching a JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2021/10/30 13:12:58 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2021/10/30 13:13:02 | Launching a JVM...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2021/10/30 13:13:02 | JVM exited while loading the application.
```

The wrapper.conf file is,

```
wrapper.java.command=../jre1.8/bin/java

# Java Main class.  This class must implement the WrapperListener interface
#  or guarantee that the WrapperManager class is initialized.  Helper
#  classes are provided to do this for you.  See the Integration section
#  of the documentation for details.
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp

# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#  needed starting from 1
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../lib/wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../jre1.8/bin/DataTransfer.jar

# Java Library Path (location of Wrapper.DLL or libwrapper.so)
#wrapper.java.library.path.1=../lib
wrapper.java.library.path.1=D:/DmsDataSender/VTunnel/lib

# Java Bits.  On applicable platforms, tells the JVM to run in 32 or 64-bit mode.
wrapper.java.additional.auto_bits=TRUE
```